# How to use __weak reference in clang?

Tags: objective-c, clang, weak-references

I wrote a simple OC file to test a `__weak` reference

```
#import "Foundation/Foundation.h"

@interface Foo : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, assign) int a;
- (void)test;
@end

@implementation Foo
- (void)test
{
    __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
    [weakSelf test];
}

@end

int main()
{
    Foo* foo = [[Foo alloc] init];
    foo.a = 3;
    [foo test];
    return 0;
}
```

Compiled with `clang -rewrite-objc keke.m` I got following error:

> cannot create __weak reference because the current deployment target does
>   not support weak references  __attribute__((objc_ownership(weak))) typeof(self) weakSelf = self;

How could I set the depoly target directly in `clang`. I tried

```
clang -rewrite-objc -stdlib=libc++ -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 keke.m
```

but no luck.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You must enable and set a runtime version. Try:

```
clang -rewrite-objc -fobjc-arc -stdlib=libc++ -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -fobjc-runtime=macosx-10.7 -Wno-deprecated-declarations keke.m
```

Comment: the `objc-runtime` is the deployment target, then what about the `macosx-version-min`?

Comment: AFAIK sets `-fmacosx-version-min` just a load command in the object file, while `-fobjc-runtime` chooses the runtime and affects the generated code.

Answer (score -1):

xcrun -sdk iphoneos clang -arch arm64 -rewrite-objc -fobjc-arc -fobjc-runtime=ios-14.0.0 **.m -o **.cpp